# jquery touchSwipe: How to get multiple images "not just one at a time" and still slide

Tags: jquery

I am currently using the following plugin http://labs.skinkers.com/content/touchSwipe/demo/11_Image_gallery_example.php

This plugin allows users to swipe from one image to another. However, if I make the #content div wider from 500px to say 700px showing a little more of the next image it no longer works. Trying to figure out how to allow more images to show without breaking... any thoughts?

PS: Reason why I am using this plug-in and not another is for the added featured of click.

Comment: What do you mean by "added feature of click"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, This demo compared to other demos I have tried has a click handler. I have had more success with this click being noticed on mobile compared to other plug-ins without a click handler already built in. http://labs.skinkers.com/touchSwipe/demo/7_Click_vs_swipe.php

Comment: I guess my real question is, why do you need a specific plugin for handling clicks. Why not use the plugin that works best for you, and just handle clicks on your own?

Comment: You're right, I thought originally that the plugin for clicks was the one I wanted to use, but then thought more about what you said and went out searching for another plugin. Found this one and was able to get that to work. http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/touchslider/

Comment: OK then. I am going to post my comment as a question and you can accept. Cool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be choosing a plugin based on its ability to handle clicks. The handling of clicks is built into javascript and something you can implement yourself. Pick the plugin that works best, and then handling clicks on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also make the div with the "container" class wider?  Try that as well.  I did and it works.

```
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 700px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks dave and yes I have tried, when swiping from right to left and reach the end it does not snap back and stay flush to the right. Instead there is a big gap between the last image and right hand side of the container. I would want this to stay flush to the right once the user has hit the end, but still show a little of the image to its left.